# Word VBA to choose a sentence

Tags: vba, ms-word

I want to choose sentences in a Word document which start with a bold character.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
Dim s As Range
For Each s In ActiveDocument.Sentences
    If s.Characters(1).Bold = True Then
        Debug.Print s
    End If
Next
```

I do not quite see what you mean by 'choose', you can use `s.Select`, but it will only work for one sentence.

EDIT re comments

Very roughly:

```
Dim s As Range
Dim doc1 As Document
Dim doc2 As Document

Set doc1 = Word.Documents("Doc1.doc")
Set doc2 = Word.Documents("Doc2.doc")

For Each s In doc1.Sentences
    If s.Characters(1).Bold = True Then
        Debug.Print s
        doc2.Select
            Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
            With Selection.Find
                ''.Text cannot be set to more than 256 characters
                .Text = s
                .Replacement.Text = ""
                .Forward = True
                .Wrap = wdFindContinue
                .Format = False
                .MatchCase = False
                .MatchWholeWord = False
                .MatchWildcards = False
                .MatchSoundsLike = False
                .MatchAllWordForms = False
            End With
            a = Selection.Find.Execute
            If a = True Then
                Selection.Characters(1).Font.Bold = True
                ''Or for the whole sentence
                Selection.Font.Bold = True
            End If
        doc1.Select
    End If
Next
```

EDIT re Comments #2

The two documents to be compared are identical, so perhaps:

```
Dim doc1 As Document
Dim doc2 As Document
Dim i As Integer

Set doc1 = Word.Documents("Doc1.doc")
Set doc2 = Word.Documents("Doc2.doc")

If doc1.Sentences.Count <> doc2.Sentences.Count Then
    MsgBox "These two documents do not match."
    Exit Sub
End If

For i = 1 To doc1.Sentences.Count
    If doc1.Sentences(i).Characters(1).Bold = True Then
        ''Debug.Print doc1.Sentences(i)
        If doc1.Sentences(i).Text = doc2.Sentences(i).Text Then
            doc2.Sentences(i).Bold = True
        Else
            MsgBox "Sentences do not match."
        End If
    End If
Next
```

Comment: yes I mean select. Actually there are 2 word documents which includes same context. one of this one includes some bold, italic titles etc. I want to find them in first document and do bold them in second document.

Comment: In that case, you can find s in document 2 within the loop and set the first character to bold. Does Compare Documents and Track Changes not suit? It might be a lot easier if they did.

Comment: I don't know if they did. it shows the different between two documents. but there is a big problem. I write you from turkey and in some bold words turkish characters is not bold. because of this I search only for first character. if it is bold. I want to do bold it in second document. but I dont know how can I do it

Comment: if first letter of sentence is bold in first document I want to do bold the sentencein second document.

Comment: Thanks a lot Remou. how will I use it? I add the code between Sub examplemacro() End Sub. as I understood I will change the Doc1 and Doc2 with my document name. after I will run the macro. is that all??

Comment: Cut and paste into a sub in Word, open two documents put the name of the document that you want to copy the bold from instead of doc1.doc and the second document as doc2.doc. Run the code. It is not finalized code, there is no error checking, it is an example.

Comment: I run the code but it makes bold only first letter of the sentence. Not all sentence. can we solve it or did you try this code?

Comment: I nearly always test code. If you notice there are two lines, `              Selection.Characters(1).Font.Bold = True` and `Selection.Font.Bold = True`, keep the second one and delete the first.

Comment: Remou thank you so much it worked:) you saved my lots of time. thanks thanks thanks for thousands of times.. first I am running the macro in first document and secondly I am running the macro in second document. it works but is it the true way?

Comment: You should only have to run the macro once with both documents open. The 'true' document is in place of doc1.doc and the document to be changed is in place of doc2.doc. The code looks at doc1 and if it finds a sentence that starts with a bold letter, it looks in doc2 for the same sentence, and if it finds one, it makes the sentence bold. It does not much matter where you put the code, as long as you get the names right.

Comment: I opened two documents with the right name. there is no problem here. but I run the code from microsoft word/view/macros. maybe there can be a problem here.

Comment: Not as long as the names are right. When you say `Set doc1 = Word.Documents("Doc1.doc")` it looks in the open documents for a document called `Doc1.doc`, if it is not there, then you have a problem :)

Comment: you right it gives error when it occurs. but I open two documents, the code run on doc1.doc but there is no change in doc2.doc after that when I run the code on doc2.doc it changes. it works properly but in two step:)

Comment: If it works, play around until you see why. It is pretty late in my part of the world and i am shutting down :)

Comment: Ok Remou I solved. after open two document and run the code only in doc2.doc and it is okey:) it is my fault:) thanks a lot to you again. byes..

Comment: hi remou; there is a problem. when macro find a sentence which is bigger than 128 character it gives -error 5854 "string parameter too long"- how can I increase this limit?

Comment: I am not getting this error. Can you edit your original post to include the code you are using, please?

Comment: sorry I couldn't understand what you mean with this sentence "Can you edit your original post to include the code you are using, please?" the error not occurs in all documents. but some documents which includes a bold sentence with 128 character it gives this error.

Comment: I tried it with a document with a long sentence, more than 128 characters, and it worked for me. Can you try a with two test documents with long sentences, just to be sure it happens every time?

Comment: can you try with more than 256 bold character?

Comment: Okay, it is not possible to find such a long sentence, however, you have said that the documents are identical, so perhaps you could go by the sentence count?

Comment: yes the documents are identical. what is the meaning of "you could go by the sentence count". Can we change the variable from range to another thing?

Comment: I posted another example, it is above, after "EDIT re Comments #2"

Comment: Thanks Remou but it is not succesful for me because two documents are not one-to-one same. all sentences are same but there are some location differences so it gives "two documents do not match error". but the code is succesful there is no long parameter error.

Comment: ok remou I understood your code. you match all sentences. but when I compare two macro first one is more successful than second one.

Comment: You can look at finding the first part of the sentence, checking that the sentence is the same, and that no more than one such sentence has been found, and then changing the font.

Comment: I have no info about creating a macro. But as I understood we should mix first and second macros. But unfortunately I have no idea how can I do it. Remou I can only wait for your help:)